# Rewrite URL using htaccess partial url

Tags: .htaccess

I am stuck with a very long code where the code generates url something like

http://cultbrands.com.au/cultbrands.com.au_images/500w_C/F1FA150.jpg

whereas it has to generate http://cultbrands.com.au/_images/500w_C/F1FA150.jpg

so the issues is the domain name is again printed after the domainname.

I can't search for the actual code for this as there is lot of code.

Is there a way I can rewrite whereas http://cultbrands.com.au/cultbrands.com.au_images as just http://cultbrands.com.au/_images

Comment: Are you asking apache to rewrite your outgoing HTML content?

Comment: If your code does not what it is supposed to do – fix the code, instead of trying to find workarounds.